# Bot Telegram sem webhook

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Estou usando a api do telegram [Telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots) para criar um bot. Já consigo enviar mensagens, arquivos, etc. Estou criando comandos para o bot "/setcommand" e quero que este comando faça algo, uma rotina, executar um script php, js, etc. Vi na documentação o uso de webhooks, acredito que a grosso modo, ao executar um comando com bot o consumidor será o telegram que vira na minha infra via HTTP consumir de um rest, estou correto? A duvida é a seguinte, como fazer o bot executar comandos sem eu precisar fornecer uma url/webhook para ele, ex: eu dou POST HTTP em diversos conteudos, acredito que fique em cash no servidores deles, como faço um comando do bot consumir algo que já foi enviado via API para o telegram?

Comment: Então, se você não está utilizando um webhook deve estar utilizando o método getUpdates, só que esta não é a forma performática, ela existe somente para "testes" onde criamos o bot, testando ele e depois disponibilizamos uma webhook. A única forma de fazer responder automaticamente é via webhook, diferente disso, se quiser manter a sua página com o getUpdates, você precisaria ter um serviço que executasse essa página a cada x segundos e respondesse as interações com o bot.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem o que você quis dizer com "consumir algo que já enviado via API", mas o fato é que toda a interação dos Bots do Telegram acontece via HTTP.

Veja mais detalhes na [API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).